# UID of email in IMAP which does not change if mail get moved

Tags: email, imap

I am unsure if this is possible with IMAP:

1. There is a particular mail in the folder Inbox.
2. Mail User Agent 1 sees this mail
3. Mail User Agent 2 moves the mail from folder Inbox to folder "sub-folder"
4. Mail User Agent 1 wants to access the particular mail.

AFAIK the IDs in IMAP are always relative to the folder (the spec calls it "mailbox").

How can Mail User Agent 1 find the new location of the mail?

Answer (score 1):

Search by its message-id. The message-id is a header field, practically all messages have a unique id because it's used so much.

Imap lets you search by header field, including the message-id field.

Comment: `Message-Id` may be easily duplicated especially if the message has been sent to multiple recipients. So it may be "the best option but with serious drawback/vulnerability".

Comment: Can you name some email clients or servers that generate duplicate IDs? I know it's easy to do, but can you name some that actually do?

Comment: I was writing about **possible** (malicious) abuse.

Comment: Like, someone sending you essentially the same message with many message-ids? I get that all the time, the subject is usually something along the lines of UNITED NATIONS DEBT RELIEF LOTTO AWARD NOTICE. What difference does it make?

Comment: That was too brief. What I meant is: Suppose that spammer sends you that spam, and maliciously uses different message-ids even though the message is essentially the same. What difference does that make?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is not possible with "basic IMAP".

AFAIK gmail offers IMAP protocol extension `X-GM-MSGID` supporting it.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions

Comment: How is the market share? How many accounts have this feature available?